# How do I draw ovals in TikZ?

Tags: pgfmath

How can I draw this graph in the pic via tikz.

[image]

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question!. Why deleting the image?

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,nodes={ellipse,draw,align=center,text=red}]
 \path node (2020) {December\\ 2020}
    node[right=of 2020] (2021) {December\\ 2021}
    node[fit=(2020)(2021),label={[node font=\Large,black]above:Math calendar}](F){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]