# How can I draw this graph in the picture attached below by using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to draw this graph in the pic via tikz, could you please help me

[image]

Comment: It is basically the same question you asked on 10th december: [How do I draw ovals in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574496/how-do-i-draw-ovals-in-tikz). Remove one oval rename the nodes. Voila ... or provide a MWE of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Alex does the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 2):

One more example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
E/.style = {ellipse, draw,
            minimum height=#1, minimum width=#1*2},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small}
                    ]
\node[E=3em, label=part 2] {part 3};
\node[E=6em, label=part 1] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,shapes,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
ell/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=2em,minimum width=8em,align=center},
elll/.style={draw,ellipse,minimum height=4em,minimum width=10em,align=center},
every label/.style={font=\scriptsize},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ell, label=90:text] at (0,0) {};
\node[elll, label=90:text] at (0,0) {};
\node[]at (0,0){\scriptsize t};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```